# Updating user list in client upon disconnection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Good day guys. Upon solving my problem here in SO. I successfully added `user` in my array `users[]` in socket.io and showed the connected `users` in the client side.

Upon the user disconnection the name of the user will be deleted using this code `delete users[socket.user];` but the name of the user remains in the client.

Can you help me on removing the name of the user guys? Thanks.

Here's my **server.js**

```
var redis = require('redis');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

var users = [];

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

res.sendfile(__dirname + '/test.html');
    });

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('adduser', function (user) {
        socket.user = user;
        users.push(user);
        updateClients();
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        delete users[socket.user];
        updateClients(); 
    });

    function updateClients() {
        io.sockets.emit('update', users);
    }

});
```

And here's my **client.html**.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    var userList = [];
    socket.on('connect', function (){
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });


    socket.on('update', function (users){
        userList = users;
        $('#user').empty();
        for(var i=0; i<userList.length; i++) {
            $('#user').append("<b>" + userList[i] + "</b></br>"); 
        }

    });
</script>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
    <b>Users</b>
    <div id="users">
        <p id="user"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what to put in the `socket.on('disconnect', function() {});` so the disconnected user and the name of the user will be removed in the client side.

Comment: Also, are you sure you can do `socket.user = user` and have the `socket.user` object persist across multiple socket messages? I'm not familiar enough with socketio to know if that works, but the [socket.io docs](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) suggest using `socket.set` and `socket.get` (in the 'Storing data associated to a client' section)

Comment: I've read Michael Mukhin's [article](http://psitsmike.com/tag/socket-io/) in socket.io chatroom. I'm not sure, but it works.

Comment: so you've confirmed that the `users` array delivered to the client is correctly updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the clients are not updating correctly client-side is because you aren't removing the correctly server-side. You can't delete an array key by its content with `delete`. Instead, do this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.user), 1);
  updateClients(); 
});
```

The problem with what you're doing is you're effectively doing this:

```
var users = [];
users.push('foo');
delete users['foo'];
```

Since `arr` is an array, `users['foo']` will map to undefined. The string `foo` is actually index one of the array, so you'd have to use `delete users[0]`, which would cause the array key to be still exist but be undefined:

```
users[0] // undefined
```

Instead, you should remove the key entirely:

```
var index = users.indexOf(socket.user);
users.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks again for helping me @hexacyanide, i'm gonna change my code later on with the code you provided. How do i remove a user 'hexacyanide' [here](http://i.imgur.com/URmw8wW.png) in the client if he disconnects? The other client also is not updating the users in the client. What will i put in the client to remove them? Thanks again sir.

Comment: is socket.io sending the `update` event? is the client receiving the event? your `socket.on('update')` function in the client should be correctly redrawing the list. add `console.log(users)` in that function to see if the client is receiving the updated list.

Comment: The update event is working. But [this](http://i.imgur.com/URmw8wW.png) is what i need to be updated. What if   the user 'hexacyanide' disconnects. His name remains [here](http://i.imgur.com/URmw8wW.png) i'm not that too good in jquery, i'm still learning. Thanks @Plato

Comment: You're deleting the wrong `div`. Do this on your client side: `$('#users').empty();` and then `for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) $('#users').append('<b>' + users[i] + '</b></br>');`.

Comment: good catch that should solve it. my personal preference would be to use `p.user` instead of `<b /><br />`: `$('#users').append($('<p class="user"></p>').text(users[i]))`

Comment: so the code will be: 
`$('#users').empty();
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
$('#users').append($('<p class="user"></p>').text(users[i]))}`

am i right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access an array item by content. Write a function to iterate across the `users` array to remove it.

```
function removeUser(username){
  var users2 = [];
  users.forEach(function(user){
    if(user === username){ return;} // do nothing this iteration
    users2.push(user); // if we haven't returned yet, add to users2
  });
  users = users2;
  return users2;
};
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  removeUser(socket.user);
  updateClients(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your effor @Plato but my problem is removing the name of the user who disconnected in the client.html (interface). :)

Comment: If the users object is being updated on the server (which I doubt because `users[socket.user]` will be `undefined`) then your update code should work fine. Either my or @hexacyanide 's solutions should correctly remove the old user from `users`.

Comment: Thanks @Plato i will also try your code later. Thanks for the effort sir. :)